# Datagridview-multiple tables to single table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have used **full join** to populate my datagridview with the contents of two tables, now I want to save the contents of the datagridview into a single table.
I don't want to use loops and I don't wanna access single cells of the datagridview.

Now anyone has a solution for this ?

and using datasource of the datagridview and its adapter is not the solution,so please reply honestly after understanding my problem.

Comment: So without loops, accessing the the cells, or the datasource eh? -1 then

Comment: Don't want to access individual cells,just want to save the contents of the datagridview in one go.

Comment: Why?  I understand it would be great if there was a DoMagic() method, but why not loop through each row?  If a method exists, that is what it will do anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using your full join to populate the Third Table, then bind the third table to the DataGridView, therefor when you make changes to the DataGridView the third table is updated automatically

try this.  I created a new winforms project, i added a button and a datgridview.  I created a public datatable and gave it columns and a row in the Form1 constructor.  When you click the button it displays the number of rows contained in the datatable.  So I run the program click the button MessageBox says 1   I add a row to the datagrid view and click the button Messagebox says 2

```
//public/Global datatable
public DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //create myTable Columns
        myTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        myTable.Columns.Add("Age");
        myTable.Columns.Add("Number");
        //add one row
        myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {"myName","myAge","myNumber"});
        bind to the datagridview
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myTable;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //display the number or rows in the datatable
        MessageBox.Show(myTable.Rows.Count.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot K'Leg for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for, but I will attempt to be of service.  You are obtaining a result set that combines two tables using a full join, and then want to output that result set into a third table?  Is that correct?

First, I would recommend creating a view for this third table.  That is probably the most efficient and dynamic solution.  If you want to present that data to your users, have the datagrid bind to the view.  If you made any changes to the two original tables, you would have to update the third "by hand".  A view does this automatically.

Comment: yes I have two tables joined together and displayed onto the datagridview,now the user can update some of the values ,now this updated joined table must be saved onto another table directly after clicking the save button.

Comment: Why does it have to save it into a third table?  Why can't you just update the source tables?  To me, this design is wasteful, and will eventually be a performance and maintenance nightmare.  But if you must, then you will have to grab the values of the edited row(s) and code an insert method to the third table in the click event of your save button.  Make sure you wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: Sir, see I have to achieve this- I am making a salary generator-that will fetch the details of the employees from two tables that are normalized and will display onto the datagridview,now the owner will make the changes according to his wish onto the datagridview and will click on the save button,now I also want that this salary list of all the staff members must be saved in one other table that can be used separately for maintaining the salary list. So this is my third table where all the values from the datagridview must go,now you got my point ?

Comment: If you save the changes to the two source tables, and bind your datagridview to the view of the query that full joins them, then you will have accomplished your requirements without out the needs of a third table at all, which is preferable.  You don't want to store duplicate data.  The only thing worse is duplicate data where the data is out of sync.  You update the 3rd table without update the first two, and that's what you'd have.  I maintain the third table should actually be a view, and your updates should be applied to your first two tables.